# document.write js issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to open a feedback window and put some js code inside. this is what i did:

```
$('#feedback').click(function(){
 mw = window.open('','','width=560,height=460');
 mw.document.write('<html><head>');
 mw.document.write('<sc'+'ript type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></scri'+'pt>');
 mw.document.write('<sc'+'ript type="text/javascript"> function feedbacken(){'+
             'var catg = $("#catg").text(); var feedback = $("#feedback").text(); alert(catg feedback);'
              +'}</scri'+'pt>');
 mw.document.write('</head><body>');
 mw.document.write('<div style="padding-left: 30px;">');
 mw.document.write('<br/> Bitte wählen Sie die Kategorie aus: <br/> ');
 mw.document.write('<select id="catg"><option>--</option><option>Technisch</option>   <option>Inhalt</option><option>Design</option></select>');
 mw.document.write('<br/><br/>Hier bitte Ihr Feedback:');
 mw.document.write('<p><textarea id="feedback" style="width:400px;height:100px"> </textarea></p>');
 mw.document.write('<button onclick="feedbacken()"> Jetzt absenden </button>');             
 mw.document.write('</div>');
 mw.document.write('</body></html>');
});
```

now, window is opening fine, but once i click the button, it is saying. `feedbacken()` function isnot defined.

can someone please hack this for me :)

this my feedback element:

```
<a id="feedback">Feedback</a>
```

Comment: First, I think you could clean all this up by putting the HTML in a separate file and opening a new window that displays that file instead of using document.write. That would make debugging this a lot easier.

Comment: If I were teaching, I would use this as a real world example of what not to do. There's too many mistakes and better ways of going about it.

Comment: @vol7ron, really? can you please tell me better way of doing it? i also dont like this way somehow

Comment: 1) like orb says, detach the doc 2) don't use `document.write` 3) don' t concatenate strings via `+` 4) if you're going to use jQuery you might as well look at using `append` and `ajax` 5) you may want to look at an `iFrame`

Comment: @vol7ron, very nice guidance. thank you, i will follow this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the main error, but this would cause an error:

```
alert(catg feedback);
```

You could change it to:

```
alert(catg + feedback);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(catg feedback);
```

That's not valid. Try something like:

```
alert(catg);
alert(feedback);
```

or:

```
alert('catg: ' + catg + ', feedback: ' + feedback);
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems.

```
alert(catg feedback)
```

should read...

```
 alert(catg, feedback)
```

Also, jQuery is not initialised in the new window.

Comment: The second `mw.document.write()` includes jQuery.